# Check deployment to application server after a build with Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, continuous-deployment

I have a job configured to automatically deploy an application to a running server. I would like to know if Jenkins provides a way to verify if this application was deployed successfully. Ideally, the build should fail when the deployment fails.

Comment: You probably not only want to know whether deployment failed but also have a mechanism in place to revert to the previous deployment in case the newer deployment did in fact fail.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has a [rundeck](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RunDeck+Plugin) plugin which might perhaps be useful.

[Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) deploys the application, and can be setup to trigger a post-deployment build on Jenkins to perform tasks like running integration tests.

Jenkins could be used to report the status of the deployment, however it might make more sense to use rundeck's dashboard instead.